# keyboard layout returning to default when using kvm

Tags: live-usb, keyboard-layout, kvm-virtualization, kvm-switch

one of the settings which I apply from a settings bash script whenever I run Ubuntu 14.04 from a live-USB, is to set the keyboard layout to British:

```
setxkbmap -layout gb
```

It works fine until I use my KVM (D-Link DKVM222). The keyboard layout gets switched to the default 'us' layout upon switching KVM control back to the live-USB machine. Note: not when switching control away from the live-USB machine.

Is there a way that it can be prevented from reverting to the default keyboard layout, preferably within my bash script?

Comment: Desktop or server?

Comment: its a desktop setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your current command (or possibly in addition to it) you may want to try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'gb')]"
```